# invalid date - When changed date format from US to UK

Tags: javascript, date

I need some help with switching the format from DD-MM-YYYY or MM-DD-YYYY to ISO Standard (YYYY-MM-DD)in JavaScript. I'm using this on a custom URL Button. 
This is what i'm doing, and **It is working fine** for **US date formats** but not working for EU dates. I get invalid date error.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")} 

var Lastdate = new  Date('{!ServiceContract.EndDate}');
```

How can I instantiate a `Date` when using a different locale?

Comment: Is this ServiceContract.EndDate is date field?

Comment: that is correct @SantanuBoral

Comment: where exactly you are facing issue? inside the custom button or some where else?

Comment: It saves fine, but when I click the button that I created, then I get alert message.

Comment: got the error replicated..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58020/discussion-between-naruto-sfdc-and-santanu-boral).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will give an issue due to locale.

So, better retrieve year, month and day portion from the date and create a Date instance based on those parameters.

It will solve locale related issues.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")} 

var month = '{!MONTH(ServiceContract.EndDate)}'; 
var year = '{!YEAR(ServiceContract.EndDate)}'; 
var day = '{!DAY(ServiceContract.EndDate)}'; 

var Lastdate = new Date (year, month, day); 

alert(Lastdate);
```

Comment: Thank you this works great! I dont know why i didnt think of this approach